# use a custom name for a wordpress child theme

Tags: php, wordpress

can I name a Wordpress Child Theme anything (the same way I can when creating a custom wordpress theme) or do I absolutely have to append the word -child to the name?

Answer (score 1):

According to official documentation:

It is recommended (though not required, especially if you're creating a theme for public use) that the name of your child theme directory is appended with '-child'. You will also want to make sure that there are no spaces in your child theme directory name, which may result in errors.

Name is completely up to you.